# Iterating through a range of ints in ksh?

Tags: shell, ksh

How can I iterate through a simple range of ints using a for loop in ksh?

For example, my script currently does this...

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
do
   #stuff
done
```

...but I'd like to extend the range way above 7. Is there a better syntax?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Curly brackets?

```
for i in {1..7}
do
   #stuff
done
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-in-bash

Comment: Curly brackets {1..7} don´t work in ksh. They do in Linux, because linux's ksh is a symlink to bash shell. Also c-like sintax doesn´t work in the proper korn shell neither.

Comment: What version of Linux has ksh symlinked to bash?

Comment: On AIX, you may need to call on `ksh93`; `ksh` was based on the older, limited, `ksh88`. Same for Solaris up to and including Solaris 10.

Comment: Thanks. Even sth like `{01..219}` works (in zsh), i.e. evaluates to "01 02 ... 09 10 11 .. 99 100 101 102 ... 219".

Answer (score 15):

While loop?

```
while [[ $i -lt 1000 ]] ; do
    # stuff
   (( i += 1 ))
done
```

Comment: Thanks - that'd do nicely, but is there no other for loop syntax?

Comment: Only this one worked out of all the versions I tried. I am on UNIX using ksh.

182     while [[ $i -lt 1000 ]] ; do
        i=$(($i+1))
        echo "asdf $i"
        done
183     history

Comment: Replace `((i+=1))` by `i=$((i+1))` if POSIX compliance is desired.

Comment: This works well after you define `i=0`. I'm running AIX 6.1.0.0 without `seq` which worked on my `7.1.0.0` new install.

Comment: This is a good solution for the AIX ksh users since the other `{1..1000}` doesn't work in AIX

Answer (score 11):

**ksh93**, Bash and zsh all understand C-like `for` loop syntax:

```
for ((i=1; i<=9; i++))
do
    echo $i
done
```

Unfortunately, while **ksh** and zsh understand the curly brace range syntax with constants and variables, Bash only handles constants (including Bash 4).

Comment: Doesn't work on AIX. This is not correct on all versions of KSH

Comment: sbtorsvr391:~/temp/pipes $ ksh
    $ for ((i=1; i<=9; i++))
    ksh: syntax error: `((' unexpected
    $

Comment: @mathtick: Are you using ksh93 (as specified in my answer)?

Comment: ksh93? I have no idea. On poorly maintained Solaris install so probably not. How to check? ksh --version does nothing.

Comment: @mathtick: Try `echo $KSH_VERSION` or `echo ${.sh.version}`

Comment: That didn't work either ...

$ echo ${.sh.version}
ksh: ${.sh.version}: bad substitution
$ echo $KSH_VERSION

$

Comment: @mathtick: In emacs mode (set -o emacs) try pressing `^V` (ctrl-v) which should show the version number. Also try using [`/bin/ksh93`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1461/ksh93-1.html) or `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` for your shell to see if they support C-style `for` loops. See the [`man` page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1461/ksh-1.html) for more information.

Comment: ksh was a sun specific ksh88 dialect up to and including solaris 10.  The opensolaris project added ksh93, and also had it replace /bin/sh and /bin/ksh.  Older scripts may have issues with the latter.

Answer (score 11):

on OpenBSD, use jot:

```
for i in `jot 10`; do echo $i ; done;
```

Comment: Oh my gosh this is it! :D

Answer (score 6):

Using `seq`:

```sh
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do 
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: @C.Ross Looks like someone installed 'seq' on your AIX box. It does not come standard (at least not on the 6.1 boxes I use)

Answer (score 5):

The following will work on AIX / Linux / Solaris ksh.

```
#!/bin/ksh

d=100

while (( $d < 200 ))
do
   echo "hdisk$d"
  (( d=$d+1 ))
done
```

Optionally if you wanted to pad to 5 places, i.e. 00100 .. 00199 you could begin with:

```
#!/bin/ksh
typeset -Z5 d
```

-Scott

Answer (score 2):

Just a few examples I use in AIX because there is no range operator or seq, abusing perl instead.

Here's a for loop, using perl like seq:

```
for X in `perl -e 'print join(" ", 1..10)'` ; do something $X ; done
```

This is similar, but I prefer while read loops over for. No backticks or issues with spaces.

```
perl -le 'print "$_ " for 1..10;' | while read X ; do xargs -tn1 ls $X ; done
```

My fav, do bash-like shell globbing, in this case permutations with perl.

```
perl -le 'print for glob "e{n,nt,t}{0,1,2,3,4,5}"' | xargs -n1 rmdev -dl
```