# for loop range not working ksh

Tags: linux, unix, shell, ksh

I tried this,

```
#!/bin/ksh
for i in {1..10}
do
  echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

in Ksh of an AIX box.
I am getting the output as,

> Welcome {1..10} times

What's wrong here?
Isn't it supposed to print from 1 to 10?.
Edit:
According to perkolator's post, from [Iterating through a range of ints in ksh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591109/ksh-iterate-through-a-range)

It works only on linux. Is there any other work around/replacements for unix box ksh?

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

is ugly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think from memory that the standard `ksh` on AIX is an older variant. It may not support the ranged for loop. Try to run it with `ksh93` instead of `ksh`. This should be in the same place as `ksh`, probably `/usr/bin`.

Otherwise, just use something old-school like:

```
i=1
while [[ $i -le 10 ]] ; do
    echo "Welcome $i times"
    i=$(expr $i + 1)
done
```

---

Actually, looking through [publib](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.baseadmn/doc/baseadmndita/korn_shell_enhanced.htm) seems to confirm this (the `ksh93` snippet) so I'd try to go down that route.

Comment: Unfortunately, Ksh93 doesn't seem to work for me here. But it is indeed there on /usr/bin.

Comment: Since older versions of shells don't have the range feature, `seq` is often used: `for i in $(seq 10)` or `for i in \`seq 10\`` (or on BSD systems, you  can use `jot`). @paxdiablo: if a shell has `[[]]` it most likely has `$(())` and you don't need to use `expr`.

Comment: Upvoted for the while-loop which solved my issue (albeit less elegantly than I would like). The ksh93 idea doesn't work on my AIX machine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason being that pre-93 ksh doesn't actually support range.

When you run it on Linux you'll tend to find that ksh is actually a link to bash or ksh93.

Try looping like :-

```
for ((i=0;i<10;i++))
do
 echo "Welcome $i time"
done
```

Comment: ksh93, Bash and zsh all understand C-like for loop syntax. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591109/how-can-i-iterate-through-a-range-of-ints-in-ksh

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the version of ksh you have does not have the range operator. I've seen this on several systems.

you can get around this with a while loop:

```
while [[ $i -lt 10 ]] ; do
    echo "Welcome $i times"
   (( i += 1 ))
done
```

On my systems i typically use perl so the script would look like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
for $i (1 .. 10) {
    echo "Welcome $i times"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check and see if jot works [see man page here](http://fuse4bsd.creo.hu/localcgi/man-cgi.cgi?jot%201) or if not, write your own little C program to do the same and call that.

The syntax for jot is something like

```
for i in `jot 1 10`
do 
    //do stuff here
done
```