# ksh scripting, For loop

Tags: ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
#########################     
for i in {1..30} ;do
  echo $i
done
```

output is:

```
{1..30}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [for loop range not working ksh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005265/for-loop-range-not-working-ksh)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`{1..30}`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) belongs to `bash`.

Use this:

```
for((i=1;i<=30;i++)); do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: +1. I hadn't thought that the Korn Shell supported arithmetic for-loops, but [apparently it does](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch06_03.htm)!

Comment: `for(())` was supported since `Ksh93`.

Comment: too bad it's not supported in mksh

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can switch to a while construction:

```
i=1
while (( i <= 30 ))
do
   echo $i
   (( i+=1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for {set x 0} {$x<10} {incr x} {
             puts "x is $x"
           }
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation of this?