# Regarding 'for' loop in KornShell

Tags: shell, scripting, for-loop, ksh

Is there a way to implement the following using 'for' in KornShell (ksh)?
Here is the C equivalent:

```
for(i=1;i<20;i++)
{
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

I was wondering if this can be implemented using just 'for' and not 'while'

I tried the following, it does not seem to work.

```
for i in [1-20]
    do

    print $i
    done
```

Please let me know your ideas and solutions.

Comment: please search the web. "ksh for" will pop up the answer in a split second. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591109/how-can-i-iterate-through-a-range-of-ints-in-ksh

Comment: depends how fast your internet connection is of course

Comment: @mat: sorry friend, i kept searching for stuff with the wrong tag ... my bad !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks as if `ksh` does not have support for range-based brace expansion or support the `(( ))` construct so to do this compactly, you'll need to call the external binary `seq` like so:

```
for i in $(seq 1 20); do
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: The ksh in Solaris however does support both (( )) and {1..20} too.... just tested them both ... Thanks for the alternate answer

Comment: Using 'seq' here is looks a bit odd. The question asks for a shell implementation of 'seq'.

Comment: 'seq 1 19' then becomes the short form of this answer ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Not really an answer, but an FYI to casual ksh users.

**Edit 2019-05-12** (Minor edits below in **bold**, other info is now <strike>stricken</strike>).

To clarify on several comments here, there are 2 ksh's available in typical vendor installations (non-Linux (maybe them too?)).

Solaris and AIX have a ksh and ksh93 (probably true for other vendors too). The base ksh is also known as ksh88. Ksh93 is described in [The New Kornshell Command and Programming Language, 1995](http://www.prenhall.com/allbooks/ptr_0131827006.html)

Linux systems that have a true ksh (not pdksh), mostly use ksh93 named as ksh.

Finally, to further confuse things, don't let the 1995 pub date trick you, ksh <strike>continues under</strike> **was under** active development by David Korn and Glen Fowler at AT&T until 2012?. **Versions were** released 2-3X per year. Some Linux versions pick up the newer versions.

These newer versions have very advanced features
(most of this taken from <strike>[AT&T research UWIN page. search for the link 'notes and changes'](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/)</strike>  (dead link) )

- compound variables composed like c structs (no c datatypes, just typeset decls) (one user claims a 500 Meg in-memory struct)
- Double precision floating point arithmetic with full C99 arithmetic ..The numbers Inf and NaN can be used in arithmetic expressions.
- TAB-TAB completion generates a numbered list of completions ...
- Support for processing/handling multibyte locales (e.g., en_US.UTF-8, hi_IN.UTF-8, ja_JP.eucJP, zh_CN.GB18030, zh_TW.BIG5 etc.) ...
- /dev/(tcp|udp|sctp)/host/sevrice now handles IPv6 addresses ...
- ... seek on a file by offset or content with new redirection operators.
- A new --showme option which allows portions of a script to behave as if -x were specified while other parts execute as usual. ...
- The [[...]] operator =~ has been added which compares the string to an extended regular expression ....
- The printf(1) builtin has been extended to support the = flag for centering a field ... (and others) ...
- view-pathing
- "Most of the utilities were developed by AT&T and conform to POSIX.2 and X/Open."

(note that ...s in above, usually indicate some qualifying information removed)

Korn and Fowler **had** also produced an advanced environment, UWIN (Unix for Windows) for people that use systems like Mingw or Cygwin, that would be worthy of a separate post. The downside for UWIN is,

- not same set of utilities as you find in your favorite Linux.
- Another file compilation environment that pretty much has to use MS Visual C (gcc support via Mingw is said to be on-the-way),
- a very small support community,
- the <strike>AT&T Common Public License V 1.0</strike> [Eclipse Public License](http://www.eclipse.org/org/documents/epl-v10.html)* is not GNU.

See <strike>[UWin main page](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/tools/uwin/)</strike>  (dead link) : unfortunately out of date, better to nose around in the dnld link above. Hmm, this is much better <strike>[Glenn Fowler's FAQ for UWin](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/uwin/faq.general.html)</strike> (also dead, Time Machine anyone?).

I hope this helps!

**Edit 2019-05-12** . The reason for the dead links?
[David Korn and Glen Fowler Laid Off (at AT&T, 2012?](https://www.unix.com/what-is-on-your-mind-/237119-david-korn-glenn-fowler-laid-off.html)

Information later surfaced that they are working at Google. I can't confirm this, so consider it as an old rumor.

AND see [Is Ksh93 dead?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246338/is-the-shell-ksh93-dead)

There still seems to be some activity at the [ast git-hub site](https://github.com/att/ast) . `ast` is the over-arching package that includes `ksh93`. You can get the fresh source code there and compile it.

---

*Here is the text of the project description. (There is considerably more information in the `README.md`).*

> ## KSH93
>
> This repository contains the AT&T Software Technology (AST) toolkit
>   from AT&T Research. As of November 2017 the development focus has been
>   shifted to the ksh (or ksh93) command and supporting code required to
>   build it.
>
> The non-ksh code of the AST project is no longer being actively
>   maintained. If you are interested in the non-ksh code see below for
>   details on which branches contain the full AST code base.
>
> The project only supports systems where the compiler and underlying
>   hardware is ASCII compatible. This includes Linux on IBM zSeries but
>   not z/OS. The nascent, incomplete, support for EBCDIC has been
>   removed. See issue #742.

*
The EPL replaced AT&T's original CPL.

Answer (score 6):

ksh93 supports the C-like `(( ...;...; ...))`:

```
for ((i=1;i<20;i+=1)); do
    printf "%d " $i
done && print
```

This will produce:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

Heck, even the old syntax (using '{' ... '}' instead of 'do ... done' will work):

```
for((i=1;i<20;i+=1))
{
   printf "%d " $i
} && print
```

In older shells, you can still get the same effect with

```
i=1 && while ((i<20)); do
    printf "%d " $i
    ((i+=1))
done && print
```

Answer (score 1):

ksh93 offers braceexpansion also if "braceexpand" is "on". Check with "set -o" and then use curly braces {}

```
for i in {1..20}
do
  print $i
done
```