# VirtualBox VM access with cygwin

Tags: bash, windows-7, cygwin, virtualbox

I cannot access my virtual machines from the cygwin console. (Windows 7, UAC is disabled)

```
Matthias@laptop0x4d53 /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox
$ ./VBoxManage list vms
```

The Windows console, however, has access to my virtual machines.

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe list vms
"GlassFish" {68874e4d-817a-4315-9ea2-38726964ac32}
"Tomcat" {2e22a7c0-9950-4593-8eda-778d404476c7}
"LAMP" {36aa6968-df52-49b5-be52-1f59c50f1527}
```

Maybe it's a problem with the user's rights. How can I access my VMs from cygwin also?

Comment: Even if UAC is disabled you may not have all rights ... is your cygwin window elevated?   Right-Click the icon and run-as-admin, you can also do that in the shortcut's properties (may still not be your issue)

Comment: @nhed This did not help, but it's always good to mention such pitfalls. :)

Comment: You might some helpful answers if you add a tag to indicate something about Windows. There are a lot to choose from. Good Luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try the official forums? There are some solutions [exporting some variables on ~/.bashrc](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=38538&p=173021&#p173021) and starting VB in headless mode (this is a recent post, from 2011). There's even an ugly hack about exporting a bunch of environment variables [using bat files instead](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1916#p7943).

```
#export VBOX_USER_HOME='/cygdrive/c/Documents\ and\ Settings/SomeNameHere/.VirtualBox/'
export VBOX_USER_HOME='C:\Documents and Settings\SomeNameHere\.VirtualBox\'
```

...or [HOWTO - virtualbox as a service on Windows (cygrunsrv.exe)](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=23536&p=104043#p104043). This is reported to be working on Cygwin 1.7b.

```
$ cygrunsrv --list
vboxd-myvm
```

Comment: setting `$VBOX_USER_HOME` in `C:\cygwin\home\[Username]\.bashrc` did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in the spirit of 'consider this possibility' ;-)

How 'married' are you to cygwin as your unix tool on windows? My experience with cygwin is that is very slow but it's strength is that it comes with a wide range of linux-like tools AND probably has the largest user-support community.

There are at least 2 alternatives to cygwin that I use and can recommend AND with a quick test DID return the list of my active vms_s. They are UWIN and MinGW.

Read my writeup about ksh and UWIN here
[Regarding 'for' loop in KornShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479433/regarding-for-loop-in-korn-shell/5527176#5527176) (2 nd msg)

ALSO check out the [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) environment. I have installed MinGW primarily to have access to gcc (outside of cygwin) and it has a fair number of linux-like tools.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to fix - you need to use Windows path syntax in your .bashrc

This - 
VBOX_USER_HOME='C:\Documents and Settings\user.VirtualBox'

Instead of this -
VBOX_USER_HOME=/cygdrive/c/users/user/.VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

all I did to get VBoxManage to work in cygwinn

$ alias VBoxManage='cmd /C VBoxManage '

example:

$ VBoxManage list vms

This alias assignment forces VBoxManage to run under the window's "cmd" shell.  Both stdin, stdout, and command switches work correctly.