# Sequence expression in bash

Tags: bash

I'm used to used the following feature of bash :

```
for i in ${1..23} ; do echo $i ; done
```

This doesn't generalize. For instance, replacing `23` by even `$p` does not work. As the documentation says, this is a purely syntactic feature.

What would you replace this with ?

*Note* : Of course, this could be done using a while and an auxiliary variable, but this is not what i'm looking for, even if it works. I'm failing back to this actually.

Comment: do you know about the `for ((i=1;i<=p;i++))` loop?

Comment: remove this, I didn't have the "full" comment (just for alone). No, I didn't know about this, thanks. Btw, you should had '$' in front of i and p.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511

Comment: Slight difference : seq evaluates the boundary only once; while the arithmetic form evaluates it at each iteration.

Comment: @Gzorg, bash allows to omit `$` in arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the seq tool to achieve the effect, I don't know if that's okay for your use case

```
~$ P=3 && for i in `seq 1 $P`; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
```

or litb's suggestion

```
~$ P=3 && for ((i=1;i<=$P;i++)); do echo $i; done
1
2
3
```

Comment: I was looking for a bash centric feature, that's why litb is better for my "use case". seq is rather neat too.

Answer (score 1):

If you have it available, the [seq](http://ss64.com/bash/seq.html) command can do similar.  Your example might then be:

```
p=23
for i in `seq 1 $p`
do
    echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 1):

On linux, there is a `seq` command (unfortunately it's missing in OS X).

```
#!/bin/bash
p=23
for i in `seq 1 $p`;
do
    echo $i
done
```

OS X workaround: http://scruss.com/blog/2008/02/08/seq-for-os-x/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$ p=18
$ a='{1..$p}'
$ for num in $( eval echo $(eval echo $a) ); do echo $num; done
```