# Perl-oneliner to bash

Tags: perl, bash

```
perl -E '$i=@{[`zypper lr`]}-2;map{`zypper rr $_`}1..$i'
```

What would be a good way to write this perl-onliner in bash. ( I would like to remove all repositores with zypper)?

Comment: @sid_com, Just to make sure I got this correct, you want to remove all repositories containing a file called zypper?

Comment: can you give an example of what you are trying to do, rather than expect people to 'reverse engineer' this perl.

Comment: That Perl program will fail when there are holes in the repo numbering.

Comment: After OS-installation I ad via script packages without having an  internet-connection. Since I don't like the error-messages, I would like to delete all repos and ad only the OS-iso-repo. Until now I have used "zypper mr -d ( all )" but since I don't like all repo-names and I don't need all default-repos I will try the remove-way ( I like the "rm -rf /etc/zypp/repos.d/*" :) ). After this installation I will ad the repos which I need.

Comment: @Anders 
"zypper is a command-line interface to ZYpp system management library.  It can be used to install, update, remove software, manage repositories, perform various queries, and more." (from man zypper).  
There are Backticks around zypper.

Comment: @sid_com, OK, thanks for the information. A bit late, but a late reply is always better then no reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zypper lr | grep -P "^\d" | cut -d'|' -f 1 | xargs sudo zypper rr
```

But much easier to simply:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/zypp/repos.d/*
```

Comment: My grep doesn't understand "^\d" so I have to use "^[0-9]".

Comment: Right, I didn't remember I had aliased `grep` to `grep -P`. When you're running zypper, you have openSUSE and I wager you do have a grep that understands Perl regexp - it just needs to be enabled specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this:

The first command counts the number of lines produced by `zypper lr` command.

So, you obtain that by:

```
COUNT_LINES=`zypper lr|tail +3|wc -l`
```

The second command merely runs `zypper rr [NUMBER]` for each number 1 through the counter; so you run the `for` loop in bash as shown in this SO question:

[How do I iterate over a range of numbers in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-in-bash)

Comment: That fails when there are holes in the numbering.

Comment: @daxim - this does 100% what the Perl one did. He asked how to convert Perl code to bash, NOT how to do XXX in bash correctly.

Comment: so we shouldn't even *tell* people when their code is going to blow up on them, so long as it's exactly what they asked for?

Comment: @hobbs - I didn't say we shouldn't. Just that I chose that in this instance (and if you peruse my many other answers, you will see that I do mean *in this instance*) I won't. Nobody's stopping someone (let's theoretically call them "daxim") to choose to answer differently, and and other people to choose to upvote what they consider the best asnwer. Isn't that what SO is supposed to work like?