# bash for loop question

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I iterate over a range of numbers in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-in-bash)

When I do this:

```
RANGE_COUNT=28
for i in {0..$RANGE_COUNT} ; do     echo $i; done
```

I get this

```
{0..28}
```

When I do this:

```
for i in {0..5} ; do     echo $i; done
```

I get this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

What's up with that and how do I make it do what I clearly intend and am obviously not stating correctly?

Comment: thx.. just bad search fu.. closing question as dup

Answer (score 4):

you can use c style for loop

```
for((i=1;i<=$RANGE_COUNT;i++))
do
  ...
done
```

or use eval

```
for i in $(eval echo {0..$RANGE_COUNT}); do echo $i; done
```

other methods include while loop

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -le "$RANGE_COUNT" ]; do echo $i; ((i++)); done
```

Answer (score 3):

From *man bash*:

> Brace expansion is performed before
>   any other expansions, and any
>   characters special to  other 
>   expansions  are    preserved in the
>   result.  It is strictly textual.  Bash
>   does not apply any syntactic
>   interpretation to the context of
>   the expansion or the text between the
>   braces.

So, it's something done early as a purely textual macro expansion, before *parameter expansion.*

Shells are highly optimized hybrids between macro processors and more formal programming languages.  In order to optimize the typical use cases, various compromises are made; sometimes the language gets more complex and sometimes limitations are accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the arithmetic notation:

```
for ((i=0; i<$RANGE_COUNT; i++)); do echo $i; done
```