# Writing a for loop in bash using a variable

Tags: bash

I want to create a for loop in bash that runs from 1 to a number stored in a variable in `bash`. I have tried doing what the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778741/writing-a-bash-for-loop-with-a-variable-top-end) question tells, but it produces this error:

```
Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 and the code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
TOP=10
for ((i=1; i<=$TOP; i++))
do
    echo $i
done
```

What does this error message mean? Here is an output image:

[image]

Comment: works fine with _GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)_

Comment: My version is GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running the script with `sh`, not `bash`.
Try:

```
bash split_history_file_test.sh
```

Comment: Jeez, didn't know that, thanks. Doesn't sh run a bash script?

Comment: @Krøllebølle The Bourne shell (sh) has a different syntax for `for` loops. The Bash command syntax is a superset of the Bourne shell command syntax.

Answer (score 10):

C-style for loop works only in few shells and bash is among them. This is syntax is not part of POSIX standard.

```
#!/bin/bash
TOP=10
for ((i=1; i<=$TOP; i++))
do
    echo $i
done
```

POSIX-compliant for loop will be the following

```
#!/bin/bash
TOP=10
for i in $(seq 1 $TOP)
do
    echo $i
done
```

This works both in bash and sh.

To know which shell you are logged in, execute the following command

```
ps -p $$
```

Where $$ is PID of current process and the current process is your shell, and `ps -p` will print information about this process.

To change your login shell use `chsh` command.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't produce that error. The bash version shipped with that ubuntu version should execute it without problems.

Note: you want to `echo $i`.

Comment: The echo $1 was just a typo, fixed now. My script still produces the above error, even though it is seemingly not supposed to.

Comment: copy-paste *your* script. how do you execute it?

Comment: I have copy-pasted in exactly my script now. The script is run by doing "sh file.sh" in the bash and I have first done "chmod +x file.sh".

Comment: I put in an image showing how i run the file. Ubuntu is run as a virtual machine using VMWare Player (shouldn't matter).