# Bash for loop with a variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a `for` loop in bash so that I can iterate numbers from 1 to a number larger than 10. In the cases where the number has only one digit, a zero should be added to its left (as in `01`).

The solution I found for that was this:

```
for i in 0{1..9} {10..43}; do
        echo "stuff$i.txt"
done
```

This works, but I wanted to have the upper limit as a variable, so I tried this:

```
max_test=43

for i in 0{1..9} {10..$max_test}; do
        echo "stuff$i.txt"
done
```

When running this, the script prints out

`stuff01.txt`

`stuff02.txt`

...

`stuff09.txt`

`stuff{10..43}.txt`

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778741/writing-a-bash-for-loop-with-a-variable-top-end), but in my situation I'd need 2 `for` loops due to that one-digit number condition. What is the best way to do what I want?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How is this a duplicate question? My issue is *not* having a variable as the top limit of an iteration, it is doing so given the context explained in the question.

Comment: I saw your edit, the `-w` ensured the 0 padding so you can use simply one `$(seq -w 1 "$max_test")`.

Comment: First, `{01..43}` will get you zero-padded two-digit numbers, at least in bash 4 and up (for example, try: `echo {0005..12}`). Second, you know by now that brace expansion is evaluated before anything else (as stated by the second paragraph of the "EXPANSION" section of the bash man page). You can get around this using `eval` (for example, `eval "echo {05..$n}"`) or arithmetic (`for ((i=5;i<=n;i++)); do printf '%02d ' $i; done`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable in brace expansion because brace expansion is done before variable expansion. You can use `seq` for example:

```
max=43
seq -w 1 "$max"
```

Comment: Note that this isn't a bash answer, and the `seq` utility is not guaranteed to be installed on every system that includes bash.