# How to construct a list from a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I iterate over a range of numbers in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-in-bash)

I am trying to print "Hello World!" 10 times via the code below, but it is printed only one time. Where am I missing the correct syntax?

```
RUNS=10

for RUN in {1..$RUNS}
do
    echo "Hello World!"
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do a brace expansion, but bash does not do double-expansion (it needs to expand `$RUNS`). You can force double-expansion by

```
for RUN in $(eval echo {1..$RUNS})
do 
    echo "Hello World!"
done
```

But I suggest you avoid this mess like the plague and just do

```
for RUN in $(seq 1 $RUNS) 
do 
    echo "Hello World!"
done
```

or

```
for ((RUN=1; RUN<RUNS; RUN++))
do 
    echo "Hello World!"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

[This question contains all the answers you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-in-bash)

In brief,  I would suggest you to use:

```
RUNS=10
for RUN in $(seq 1 $RUNS)
do
    echo "Hello World!"
done
```

since it will more likely work on other shells too.

If you want to avoid the overhead of the subshell, you can use:

```
RUNS=10
i=0;
while [ $i -lt $RUNS ]
do
    echo "Hello World!"
    i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Comment: this fragment spawns child process _seq_, quite an overhead for a simple for-loop

Comment: That's the way to do it for maximum compatibility with POSIX shell.  Have a look [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) and [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) for other forms of bashisms.

Comment: this question is about Bash, neither about POSIX shell, nor about compatibility with POSIX shell

Comment: Absolutely.  Also the question is not a about performance...

Answer (score 0):

*{A..B}* syntax does not seem to be substituting variables

```
for ((i=0; i < $RUNS; ++i)); do echo "hello world"; done
```

Comment: More specifically, brace expansion occurs before parameter expansion. As brace expansion requires constants, the whole construct is treated as a single string rather than being expanded.