# Bash for loop - naming after n (which is user's input)

Tags: bash

I am looping over the commands with `for i in {1..n}` loop and want output files to have `n` extension.

For example:

```
  for i in {1..2}
  do cat FILE > ${i}_output
  done
```

However `n` is user's input:

```
  echo 'Please enter n'
  read number
  for i in {1.."$number"}
  do 
    commands > ${i}_output
  done
```

Loop rolls over `n` times - this works fine, but my output looks like this `{1..n}_output`.

How can I name my files in such loop?

**Edit**

Also tried this

```
  for i in {1.."$number"} 
  do
    k=`echo ${n} | tr -d '}' | cut -d "." -f 3`
    commands > ${k}_output
  done
```

But it's not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-in-bash

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a ["C-style" `for`-loop](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html#FORLOOPC):

```
echo 'Please enter n'
read number
for ((i = 1; i <= number; i++))
do 
    commands > ${i}_output
done
```

Note that the `$` is not required ahead of `number` or `i` in the `for`-loop header but [double-parentheses](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html#DBLPARENSREF) are required.

Answer (score 3):

The range parameter in for loop works only with constant values. So replace `{1..$num}` with a value like: `{1..10}`.

OR

Change the for loop to:

```
  for((i=1;i<=number;i++))
```

Comment: `i <= number` or you'll miss the last element. And you don't need the `$` there, either (see my answer).

Comment: @Johnsyweb Fixed it. But $ doesn't hurt either :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for loop ( similar to the ones found in langaues like C, C++ etc):

```
echo 'Please enter n'
read number
for (( i=1; i <= $number; i++ ))
do
  commands > ${i}_output
done
```

Comment: `i <= number`. No `$`.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, I tried that out. Seems both are working. :)

Comment: Great :-) Every day's a school-day.

Comment: Right..I learned something new too. Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using `seq (1)` instead. As in `for i in $(seq 1 $number)`.

Comment: `seq` involves the execution of an external command that may slow things down, but I'm not sure that warrants a downvote.