# bash for loop: a range of numbers

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have the following code in an .sh file:

```
for num in {1..10}
do
  echo $num
done
```

Which should print numbers from 1 to 10. But, this is what I get:

```
{1..10}
```

Also, using C-like sytax doesn't work either:

```
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++))
```

This gets me an error:

```
Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

The version of bash that I have is 4.2.25.

Comment: Your code works fine for me in 4.1.5

Comment: You can also print a range of numbers using seq. Try "seq 1 5".

Comment: If you execute `bash` as `sh`, it won't work; if you execute `bash` as `bash`, it will work.

Comment: C-syntax works when you do let i= 0 before the for loop condition.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The code should be as follows (note the shebang says `bash`, not `sh`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bash version ${BASH_VERSION}..."
for i in {1..10}
do
    echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

You can use `{0..10..1}` if you want to start from 0.

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/.

Comment: This: (note the shebang says bash, not sh)

Comment: The `..1` is unnecessary.

Comment: at least it looks to me that he is executing a shell script on a bash shell.

Comment: Adding the shebang did the trick. The c-like syntax still doesn't work, though.

Comment: "..1" doesn't parse in MacOSX Bash.

Comment: This does not work for me.~/u/tmp> cat try
#!/bin/bash
# 

for integer in {1..10..1} 
do
 echo "integer is $integer"
done
~/u/tmp> ./try
integer is {1..10..1}
~/u/tmp>

Comment: "..1" step size was added in bash 4.0+

Comment: This answer ranges from 0-10. The loop in the question ranges from 1-10. My guess is that the questioner was accidentally running sh, not bash - his loop was perfect otherwise.

Comment: Note this does *not* work when using variables inside `{start..end..step}`, e.g. `{0..$end..1}`. With bash 5.0.17 `end=10; for i in {0..$end..1}; do echo $i; done` yields the output `{0..10..1}`.

Comment: @balu Note that the question was not about using variables, so the answer is viable. If you need variables, then you can instead use the C-style version: `for (( $i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += $incr )) ...`. That works.

Comment: @AlexisWilke I wasn't criticizing your answer, I just thought I'd leave a note for anyone else who'd try to use variables like I did.

Comment: I like how `for i in {01..10}`  will give you padded numbers ... `01` ... `02` ....