# Why this shell script doesn't work?

Tags: linux, shell

```
  n=5
  for i in {1..$[n]}
  do 
       echo $i
  done
```

it gives:

```
{1..5}
```

But I think it should output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Why it gives such a strange output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash

Comment: you cannot use brace-expansion with a parameter in bash due to the order of evaluation. Use `seq` instead. And your syntax is wrong, doesn't matter since it wont work anyway, but still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is almost a riddle.   The expansion of the braces is being done prior to the variable expansion. The bash beginners guide has some good detail on [expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html)
There are a brazillion ways to do this in bash.
You could start with:

```
n=5
for i in $(eval echo {1..$n})
do
   echo $i
done
```