# How do I iterate over multiple, discontinuous ranges in a bash for loop

Tags: bash

Note: I am NOT asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash)

I looked for information on how to loop over a range of *discontiguous* numbers such as 0,1,2,4,5,6,7,9,11 without having to put the numbers in by hand and still use the ranges.

The obvious way would be to do this:

```
for i in 0 1 2 4 5 6 7 9 11; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: My question is: where did these arbitrary sub-ranges come from in the first place?

Comment: Barmar -- suppose I want to run something with ssh on multiple machines. When they were initially installed, IT installed them in a one-up fashion. Then a few of them were re-purposed. Now I need to loop over a *discontiguous* list of numbers.

Comment: And you don't have a list of them in a file somewhere, you have to hard-code it into each script that wants to do something with them?

Comment: Which means that the next time one of them is repurposed or you add new machines, you'll need to update all the scripts that contain this `for` loop. Do yourself a favor and make a file.

Comment: I just work here. ;-)

Comment: @Barmar there are other reasons why you might want to use discontinuous numbers. For example, file names having some numerical suffix that is meaningful and distinguishes them from the other files with the same stem. So I think that it is a valid question.

Comment: @LynseyHall I maintain my original position: if there's no rule to generate the number, then they're arbitrary and probably should be listed in a file or database. The only thing the accepted answer does is save a few characters (and not even that -- `{0..2}` is 1 more character than `0 1 2`).

Comment: @Barmar There are many reasons to use a disjointed numeric sequence that are single-use and so do not merit the overhead of a file or a database. And so I find your solution useful on a regular basis (just used it again for a completely different situation yesterday).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
for i in {0..2} {4..6} {7..11..2}; do echo $i; done
```

See the documentation of bash [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

Comment: Thanks for the search terms. Couldn't think how to look for it.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: oops, didn't realise there were missing numbers.

Updated: Define ranges and then use a while loop for each range. e.g.

```
ranges="0-2 4-7 9 11"
for range in $ranges
do
    min=${range%-*}
    max=${range#*-}
    i=$min
    while [ $i -le $max ]
    do
        echo $i
        i=$(( $i + 1 ))
    done
done
```

http://ideone.com/T80tfB

Comment: This doesn't have the discontinuities I wanted.

Comment: Did you miss the word _discontiguous_ in the question?

Comment: Yes I did sorry. Fixed it

Comment: That's a clever solution, +1

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, `brace expansion` provides a way to select ranges, but you can also assign the results of multiple brace expansions to a variable using `echo {..} {..}`. This may cut down on the typing in the body of the `for` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

range="`echo {2..6} {31..35} {50..100..10}`"

for i in $range; do echo $i; done

exit 0
```

**output:**

```
2
3
4
5
6
31
32
33
34
35
50
60
70
80
90
100
```

Comment: I think the range variable should not have "echo" in it.

Comment: You must, otherwise there is no expansion.

Comment: ah -- I understand now. By the time it gets to the for loop, it's just a list of numbers in a string.

Comment: I don't see how this cuts down on anything in the body of the loop. However, it's useful if you'll have multiple loops over the same set, since you don't have to repeat the list each time.

Comment: I don't know, you count: `for i in $range;` **or** `for i in $(echo {2..6} {31..35} {50..100..10})`; -- which is shorter?

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in `cat file.txt`; do echo $i; done
```

where file.txt contains:

```
0
1
2
4
5
6
7
9
11
```

Comment: I didn't say this explicitly in my question, but the point of iterating over something BESIDES a list of numbers would be to save work. up-vote for sheer cheek.

Comment: for those who decided to use this approach, please note it is ` not ' around the cat command