# how to provide two set of ranges to for loop

Tags: bash

How can I store numbers from two loops into one array and take average of those numbers?

```
#!/bin/bash
START_se1=55761
END_se1=55770
START_set2=55900
END_set2=55917
#set1
for ID in {$START_set1..$END_set1}
do
  myarr1=($(echo ${ID}))
done

#set2
for ID in {$START_set2..$END_set2}
do
  myarr2=($(echo ${ID}))
done

app=( "${myarr1[@]}" "${myarr2[@]}" )
echo $app
```

This code gives only last ID in myarr1 which is  55770

Thanks

Comment: Probably related: [How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/169511/1983854). Not sure if it is the case

Comment: you do not need to run command execution `$(...)`. just assign the id. `{$START_set1..$END_set1}` really works? if so which shell hides behind bash? - ok - learned something :)

Answer (score 0):

initialize your array before the loop `myarr1=()` and fill it using `myarr1[${#myarr1[@]}]=${ID}`. print out after you filled it with `echo ${myarr1[@]}`.hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** you got some typos, list and access faults. consider this snippet.

```
#!/bin/bash
START_set1=55761 # typo
END_set1=55770 # typo
START_set2=55900
END_set2=55917

#set1
myarr1=()
for ID in $(seq $START_set1 1 $END_set1); do # typo, range iteration
  myarr1[${#myarr1[@]}]=${ID} # fill set1
done
echo ${myarr1[@]}
echo ---

#set2
myarr2=()
for ID in $(seq $START_set2 1 $END_set2); do # range iteration
  myarr2[${#myarr2[@]}]=${ID} # fill set2
done
echo ${myarr2[@]}
echo ---

app=( "${myarr1[@]}" "${myarr2[@]}" )
echo ${app[@]} # access all elements, like above
```