# Shell script echo{$1..$2}

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $1+$2 -eq 1 ]
then : ;
else echo {$1..$2}
fi
```

Hello guys,
got this code, it should do: write numbers from arg1 to arg2 ($1=3,$2=6 then 3 4 5 6 should be output)and if args are 0 and 1 or 0 and 1 it should do nothing but actually got error and bad output :

```
./kek1.sh: 2: [: Illegal number: 1+2
{1..2}
```

anyone know whats wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here:

- Math must be performed inside an arithmetic expression `$(( ... ))`
- `{...}` is not supported by `/bin/sh`.
- Not actually a problem, but you can negate the `if` condition and avoid the `else` clause altogether.

A correct solution is

```
if ! [ $(( $1 + $2 )) -eq 1 ]; then
    printf "$1"
    i=$1
    while [ "$i" -lt "$2" ]; do
        i=$((i+1))
        printf " %d" "$i"
    done
fi
```

If available, you can use the `seq` command instead of the `while` loop:

```
if ! [ $(( $1 + $2 )) -eq 1 ]; then
    seq "$1" "$2"
fi
```