# bash variable for upper limit of for loop number syntax

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop

If I create a bash loop like this, using literal numbers, all works as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10};  do
  echo $i 
done
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

But if I want to use the upper limit in a variable, I can't seem to get it it right.  Here are my four attempts:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=10

for i in {1..$n};  do
  echo $i 
done

for i in {1.."$n"}; do 
  echo $i
done

for i in {1..${n}};  do
  echo $i 
done

for i in {1.."${n}"};  do
  echo $i 
done
```

And the output is now:

```
{1..10}
{1..10}
{1..10}
{1..10}
```

Not what I wanted... :(

To be clear about the question:

How do I use a variable as the limit for the range syntax in a bash for loop?

Comment: [Check this answer in linked Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/171041/548225)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `{...}`; use a C-style for loop.

```
for ((i=1; i <= $n; i++)); do
```

Brace expansion occurs before parameter expansion, so you can't generate a variable-length sequence without using `eval`. This is also more efficient, as you don't need to generate a possibly large list of indices before the loop begins.

Comment: Thanks, chepner.  That solves my problem and provides a bit of background with respect to why this behavior is expected.