# how to download batch of data with linux command line?

Tags: linux, bash, batch-processing

For example I want to download data from:
http://nimbus.cos.uidaho.edu/DATA/OBS/

with the link:

http://nimbus.cos.uidaho.edu/DATA/OBS/pr_1979.nc

to

http://nimbus.cos.uidaho.edu/DATA/OBS/pr_2015.nc

How can I write a script to download all of them? with `wget`?and how to loop the links from 1979 to 2015?

Comment: Is the range only 1979-2015, or are you looking for something more dynamic that checks whether a year exists first?

Comment: Well, yes for this example, I can check that by my eyes for simplicity. So just look for the looping code. Maybe some script like `wget http://nimbus.cos.uidaho.edu/DATA/OBS/pr_*.nc` or `wget .../pr_[1979-2015].nc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like a for loop iterating over a predefined series.

Untested code:

```
for i in {1979..2015}; do
  wget http://nimbus.cos.uidaho.edu/DATA/OBS/pr_$i.nc
done
```

Comment: You might also be interested in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful! Do you have any suggested documents or books or tutorials on learning this kind of bash code?

Comment: @breezeintopl honestly, not really. you might try posting that as a question on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com Personally, I just search stack overflow for anything I need to do, and the answers are most usually here already.

Answer (score 5):

`wget` can take file as input which contains URLs per line.

```
wget -ci url_file
```

`-i` : input file
`-c` : resume functionality

So all you need to do is put the URLs in a file and use that file with wget.

A simple loop like [Jeff Puckett II's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37233488/3744681) will be sufficient for your particular case, but if you happen to deal with more complex situations (random urls), this method may come in handy.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer! This actually brings another (two) problem(s) for me for a long time(which I usually do it by hand T. T): 1. How can I create a file with repeated content "...pr_1979.nc \n ...\n ...pr_2015.nc"? 2. How can I create 30+ files with names like "1979.txt" and content "http.../pr_1979.nc"? Well, I think I can use, say R, to concatenate long content strings with variable, say x=1979. But I don't think this is the usual way to do this. Since I am not a computer science major, I am not familiar with how to create a batch of files. (Maybe, geeks use vim to do this?)

Comment: OK, so maybe, based on the above answer, it is something like `echo $text1$i$text2 >> filename$i ;` in the loop.

Comment: @breezeintopl : yes, but it defeats the purpose (creating each file for each link).`filename$i` should be `filename` so that all links go into the same file. Though I generally extract the URLs from the html source with text editor, generally with [tag:sed].

Comment: OK, got it. Thank you so much!