# What is the most portable way to write an iteration (for, while) loop in a (POSIX) shell script?

Tags: shell, loops, iteration, posix

From what I've read on stack, here's one syntax :

```
iterator=0
while [ "$iterator" -lt 100 ]
do 
  printf "$iterator" 
  iterator=`expr $iterator + 1 `
done
```

Anybody cares to improve on this?

Aim is to make an iteration loop that would be most portable on posix systems.

[EDIT] 
just found this question which has very relevant answers:
[How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash) but I'd like an answer here because I believe my question is more precise for future searches.

Comment: What do you want to iterate over?

Comment: Integers. Here I'm using -lt 100 as an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash)

Comment: We'd rather collect good answers in one place than have them scattered across many similar questions. The distinction between Bash and POSIX make this less cut and dried, but the nominated duplicate has many anwers which are portable, and are marked as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You probably want a newline in the `printf` format; otherwise, the numbers are all printed on a single line with no spacing.
- You should use `$(…)` in place of the back-ticks.
- Even POSIX shells support `iterator=$(( $iterator + 1 ))` (where the `$(( … ))` notation is distinct from the `$( … )` notation!), so you don't need to use `expr`.

Putting those together:

```
iterator=0
while [ $iterator -lt 100 ]
do
    printf '%d\n' $iterator
    iterator=$(( $iterator + 1 ))
done
```

There are other options if you have a command such as `seq` available, but that isn't a part of POSIX.

There are those who would demand that the variables be enclosed in quotes when referenced.  There's no harm in doing so, and in much general code, I would do so.  But here the values are strictly controlled by the script; there is no way for blanks or other awkward characters to get in the way of the correct operation of the script.

Comment: about the newline : yeah I kind of neglected that :)

Comment: about `seq` : not POSIX indeed, and calling a subprocess, so don't want that.

Comment: You didn't mind using sub-processes with the back-ticks and `expr`, so I'm not sure why `seq` would be a problem because it is a sub-process.  Not POSIX is another issue altogether — and inescapable.  But `awk 'BEGIN{for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) print i}` is impeccably POSIX, though still with a sub-process.

Comment: Incidentally, my answer is very close to the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31365662/15168) by [Ciro Santilli 巴拿馬文件 六四事件 法轮功](http://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-%e5%b7%b4%e6%8b%bf%e9%a6%ac%e6%96%87%e4%bb%b6-%e5%85%ad%e5%9b%9b%e4%ba%8b%e4%bb%b6-%e6%b3%95%e8%bd%ae%e5%8a%9f) in your cross-referenced question.

Comment: Yes, not using subprocesses is another thing. Let's not confuse stuff up. Btw, a closing quote is missing in you awk syntax.

Comment: Yeah on the close quote.  I spotted it over ten minutes later when it was uneditable.  Sorry!

Comment: no worries, thanks for the great answer. I'm sure it's going to help people due to the specific title with usefull keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do...

```
while [ "$((iterator+=1))" -le 100 ]; do
    printf '%d\n' "$iterator"
done
```