# How to create multiple files in each directories and then compress it through tar (BASH)

Tags: bash

What I am currently struggling is to create multiple files and storing it into each directory.
I have made 100 directories like this:

```
mkdir ./dir.{01..100}
```

What I want is to create 100 text files for each directory. So that the result will show like:

> click on dir.01 at home dir, which has files named: 01.txt to 100.txt

Also, I want to compress all 100 directories, each containing 100 text files into one using tar.

I am struggling with:

1. creating 100 text files each in 100 directories
2. using tar to zip all 100 directories together.

I am more interested in making creating 100 text files IN 100 directories. Also I am MUCH MORE interested in how to use tar to join all 100 directories together in specific file (fdtar) for instance.

Comment: read the docs on bash about `for` loop. check examples like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash)

Comment: That's already done. I know how to iterate over a range of numbers. I made directories in such manner --> ./dir/{01..100} which actually returns the samething

Comment: `tar` is an archive format, not a compression one. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you need two things. First, you have 100 directories and need to create a file in each. With a `for` loop in `bash` run from the parent directory where all other directories you have created are:

```
for n in dir.*
do
  f=`echo $n | sed s/dir\.//`
  echo "This is file $n" >"$n/$f.txt"
done
```

Regarding `tar` that is even easier because `tar` will take multiple directories and glue them together. From the parent directory try:

```
tar cvf fd.tar dir.*
```

The `c` option will create the archive. `v` will tell `tar` to print all it is doing so you know what is happening. `f directories.tar` will create the archive with that name.

When you undo the *tar* operation, you will use:

```
tar xvf fd.tar
```

In this case `x` will extract the contents of the *tar* archive and will create all 100 directories for you at the directory from which you invoke it.

Note that I have used `fd.tar` and not `fdtar` as the `.tar` extension is the customary way to signal that the file is a *tar* archive.

Comment: This will break in multiple places if one of the directories contains a space or some shell metacharacters. Always, *always* use double quotes around variables which contain file names. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: Suggestion accepted, thank you. Although the problem was stated with no such cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with empty files,

```
touch ./dir.{01..100}/{01..100}.txt
```

If you need each file to contain something, use that as the driver in a loop:

```
for file in ./dir.{01..100}/{01..100}.txt; do
    printf "This is the file %s\n" "$file">"$file"
done
```

This could bump into `ARG_MAX` ("argument list too long") on some platforms, but it works fine on MacOS and should work fine on any reasonably standard Linux.

Splitting the loop into an inner and an outer loop could work around that problem:

```
for dir in ./dir.{01..100}; do
    for file in {01..100}.txt; do
        printf "This is file %s/%s\n" >"$dir/$file"
    done
done
```