# Bash script loop through netCDF files via placeholder and use cdo commands

Tags: bash, for-loop, netcdf, cdo-climate

I want to loop through 40 netCDF files. There are 20 files with the variable `PRECC` and 20 files with the variable `PRECL("modelmember001.PRECC.192001-200512.nc", "modelmember002.PRECC.192001-200512.nc", ... ,"modelmember020.PRECC.192001-200512.nc"` and for `PRECL` respectively).

I need to perform multiple cdo (climate data operator) commands with the loop (add PRECC and PRECL files, and change time series form 1920-2005 to 1955-2005).

This is the code that I use:

```
  datadir="path_to_mydatat"
    workdir="path_to_folder_for_newfiles"
    members="{001 .. 020}"

    for model in $members
    do

    echo 'working with model' ${model}

    echo cdo -s add ${datadir}/modelmember${members}.PRECC.192001-200512.nc${datadir}/modelmember${members}.PRECL.192001-200512.nc ${workdir}/modelmember${members}PRECT.192001-200512.nc
    # echo cdo -s selyear,1955/2005 ${workdir}/modelmember${members}.PRECT.192001-200512.nc ${workdir}/modelmember${members}.PRECT.195501-200512.nc
```

Eventually I need 20 files with the name

```
"modelmember001.PRECT.195501-200512.nc", "modelmember002.PRECT.195501-200512.nc", ... , "modelmember020.PRECT.195501-200512.nc"
```

This is what I get when I run my code (deliberately with an "echo" in front of the cdo line):

```
$./cdo_add.sh

{001 .. 020}

working with model {001

cdo -s add /path_to_mydatat/modelmember{001 .. 020}.PRECC.192001-200512.nc         /path_to_mydatat/modelmember{001 .. 020}.PRECL.192001-200512.nc  /path_to_folder_for_newfiles/modelmember{001 .. 020}.PRECT.192001-200512.nc

working with model ..

cdo -s add /path_to_mydatat/modelmember{001 .. 020}.PRECC.192001-200512.nc /path_to_mydatat/modelmember{001 .. 020}.PRECL.192001-200512.nc /path_to_folder_for_newfiles/modelmember{001 .. 020}.PRECT.192001-200512.nc

working with model 020}

cdo -s add /path_to_mydatat/modelmember{001 .. 020}.PRECC.192001-200512.nc /path_to_mydatat/modelmember{001 .. 020}.PRECL.192001-200512.nc /path_to_folder_for_newfiles/modelmember{001 .. 020}.PRECT.192001-200512.nc
```

My code doesn't seem to loop through the members. There is something wrong with the way I use the placeholder "members" but I can't figure out how to fix it. 
Does anyone have a suggestion? 
Cheers!

Comment: `for model in {001..020}` -- you can use a variable. Get rid of `members="{001 .. 020}"` (it results in looping on `001` then `..` then `020`)

Comment: here is a similar question with solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/169511/754550

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not seem to loop because you cannot assign a brace expansion to a variable and expect it to expand when substituted in a `for` loop. The following saves the literal string `"{001 .. 020}"` to the variable `members`, e.g.

```
members="{001 .. 020}"
```

When you use `members` in `for model in $members`, normal word-splitting occurs because it is just a string and you loop once with `001`, then with `..` and finally with `020` -- not the expected sequence from `001, 002, 003, ... 020`. (there should be no spaces between the number and `..` to begin with -- but that still doesn't allow you to use the expansion in a variable)

To properly use the expansion, get rid of the `members` variable altogether and use `{001..020}` in the loop, e.g.

```
for model in {001..020}   ## (notice NO space between 001 and ..)
```

example:

```
$ for m in {001..020}; do echo $m; done
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
010
011
012
013
014
015
016
017
018
019
020
```

That will allow you to loop with your sequence in `model`.

From the conversation in the comments, I know understand that you have 40 files prefixed by `modelmemberXXX` (where `XXX` is `001-020`) followed by `.PRECC*` or `.PRECL*` (20 files each) that you want to coordinate feeding matching pairs to a cdo command. While the preferred way would be to loop over one matching glob, e.g. `for i in modelmember*.PRECC*; do`, you can also use your brace expansion approach, e.g.

```
for i in {001..020}
do 
    a=$(echo modelmember${i}.PRECC*)
    b=$(echo modelmember${i}.PRECL*)
    if [ -e "$a" ] && [ -f "$b" ]
    then
        printf "%s\n%s\n\n" "$a" "$b"
    fi
done
```

(note the `[ -e "$a" ] && [ -f "$b" ]` test just makes sure both files in the pair exist before proceeding with the command (`printf` here))

**Example Output**

```
modelmember001.PRECC.192001-200512.nc
modelmember001.PRECL.192001-200512.nc

modelmember002.PRECC.192001-200512.nc
modelmember002.PRECL.192001-200512.nc

modelmember003.PRECC.192001-200512.nc
modelmember003.PRECL.192001-200512.nc
...
modelmember020.PRECC.192001-200512.nc
modelmember020.PRECL.192001-200512.nc
```

You simply need to make use of `$a` and `$b` with whatever `cdo_cmd` you need within the loop. (as noted in the comments, you need to change to the directory containing the files, or precede the filenames with `path/to/the/files`)

**Preferred Way**

Rather than using your brace expansion, it is probably preferred to loop over one set (either `PRECC` or `PRECL`), validate the other exists, then execute the command, e.g.

```
for i in modelmember*.PRECC* 
do
    b="${i/PRECC/PRECL}"
    if [ -e "$i" ] && [ -f "$b" ]
    then
        printf "%s\n%s\n\n" "$i" "$b"
    fi
done
```

(same output)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! This solves the problem of the looping. If I get rid of the variable "members" though, how do I tell the loop to perform the cdo functions pairwise (e.g.  `modelmember001PRECC.192001-200512.nc` and `modelmember001PRECL.192001-200512.nc` ?

Comment: Does the variable `PRECL` really hold comma separated values? e.g. `PRECL("modelmember001.PRECC.192001-200512.nc", "modelmember002.PRECC.192001-200512.nc",...`?? If it were me, I would read one variable into an array (e.g. `IFS=$', \t\n'; arrayCL=(echo $PRECL)`, then loop over each file in that array `for i in ${arrayCL[@]}; do somecdocmd "$i" ${i/PRECC/PRECL}"; done` where the *parameter expansion with substring replacement* changes `PRECC` to `PRECL` to give you the corresponding pair file. (you can add a `test -e ${i/PRECC/PRECL}"` to make sure the paired file exists.)

Comment: If `PRECL(...)` is already an array, then just loop over the indexes in each array (assuming they have the same number of elements) `for ((i = 0; i < ${#PRECL[@]}; i++)); do somecdocmd "${PRECL[I]}" "${PRECC[I]}"; done`. You can test that the elements are pairs with the parameter expansion in the previous comment.

Comment: Edit -- in the first comment it should be `arrayCL=($(echo $PRECL))` - I forgot the command substitution. You can use a *herestring* as well in bash `$(<<<$PRECL)`. (you can use a similar expansion to solve your rename to `CT` as well, e.g. `${i/PRECC/PRECT}` to replace the `CC` to `CT` (or `CL` to `CT`))

Comment: Grrr this is why you do not use ALLCAPS for variable names. It should be `do somecdocmd "${PRECL[i]}" "${PRECC[i]}"` in the 2nd comment -- caps lock was still on `:(`

Comment: I have 40 individual files in netCDF format. Each file consists of multiple variables e.g. the variable `PRECC` (or `PRECL` ) itself is 3 dimensional (time, lon, lat).
So no comma separated files nor arrays. Just a folder with 40 files (20 have `PRECL` and `PRECC` in their name respectively).
I know that there is a way to do it via the "member" option, I have done it before, just can't figure out how exactly.
Is there no way to define the members="001..020" in a way so it uses one argument after the other in the file name?

Comment: @DavidCRankin : do you think your approach would still work in my case (no array, nor comma separated values)?

Comment: Or sure, in the directory (or appending a path to the variables). `for model in {001..020}; do [ -e "PRECL*$model*" ] && [ -e "PRECC*$model*" ] && somecdocmd "PRECL*$model*"; done` would work by verifying both `XXX` (e.g. `001`) files exist and then running `somecdocmd` with each as arguments. You must not have 3 files with the same `XXX` in the name. (you can narrow the globbing further, e.g. `"PRECC*$model*.nc"` or adding any other characteristics you like)

Comment: @Angie - look at the addition to the answer. I believe I understand your file pair needs. Also note the comment about the *preferred way* to loop over the set of files.

Comment: Glad to help. You will be a bash wizard soon. Note, the `-e` (exists) should probably be `-f` (file) in both `[ ... ]` tests for consistency sake. Either `-e` exists, `-f` file or `-r` readable, will work, but `-f` will distinguish a file from a directory in case you happened to have a stray directory with the expected filename. Good luck and always use [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) for good references and [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for good checking.