# Running pi.sh using for loops for N times

Tags: linux, shell

how to run the pi.sh for certain number of times using for loop?  to test this write a script that runs pi.sh seven times with values of N ranging from 1 through 7.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried.