# What is the difference between these two things?

Tags: linux, bash, eval, brace-expansion

I just wanted to know what is the difference between:

`echo {$number1..$number2}`

AND

`eval echo {$number1..$number2}`

Of course, imagine that there is a value in $number1 and $number2.
With the first option is just not working, but with the second option it works. I'm not the typical guy that only want something to work, I want to understand why it happens like that so, why exactly is this happening like this?

Comment: An eval could execute any command.

Comment: yes but, in the first form I'm executing the command too. So what is the real difference? the process?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5723526/1899640) on a related question explains why brace expansion doesn't work together with parameter expansion

Comment: The bash manpage isn't the easiest read but the **EXPANSION** section may be of some help.

Answer (score 9):

#### Why the first expression does not work as expected

1. Brace expansion is executed before variable expansion. `$number1..$number2` is not a valid sequence expression, so the whole expression is left unchanged.
2. After that, variable expansion takes place, resulting in the expression `{1..3}` (given that `number1=1` and `number2=3`).

#### Why the second expression does

Your second example works the same, except that the result of variable expansion (`{1..3}`) is passed to Bash again via `eval`, giving brace expansion a second chance: `1..3` is a correctly formed sequence expression and therefore brace expansion yields the expected result:

```
1 2 3
```

#### Avoid using `eval`

Using `eval` should generally be avoided, as it easily introduces security problems: If `number1` or `number2` receive input and are not properly sanitized, malicious code can be injected into your program. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4024473) for ways to replace `eval` in various use cases.

In your specific example, the sequence could instead be created by a for loop combined with arithmetic evaluation:

```
for ((i=number1 ; i<=number2; i+=1)); do echo -n "$i" ; done | xargs
1 2 3
```

A popular non-Bash solution would be to use `seq` (as pointed out by Walter A in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54501835/4024473)) as in `seq "$number1" "$number2" | xargs`.

Note: `xargs` joins multi-line output to a single line in these examples.

#### Further information

This [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5723526/4024473) gives more information on the topic.

Also, the [EXPANSION section](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXPANSION) in the [bash(1) manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) is pretty informative on sequence and workings of different expansion mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

The substitution of the variables is to late.
You can avoid `eval` with

```
seq -s " " "$number1" "$number2"
```