# Bash script for loop which the last statement is first calculated

Tags: bash, for-loop

I wrote this bash script

```
x=64
y=1
ans=$((x-y))
z=`expr $ans`
for i in {1..$z}
do 
    echo $i
done
```

Actually, I would like to print i values from 1 to 63, 63 which is first 
obtained from the above addition. But it just prints {1..63}

Can someone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Please don't answer this question. This is a 1:1 duplicate** of [How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash). Which has been asked over and over again.

Comment: What are you trying to do with ``z=`expr $ans` ``? `z=$((x-y))` or just `((z=x-y))` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You're best of using a C-style for loop:

```
for ((n=$y; n<$x; n++)); do
    echo $n
done
```

Answer (score 0):

using seq :

```
for i in $(seq 1 $z) 
do 
   echo $i 
done
```