# Bash - Getting an N number of arguments and creating an N amount of .txt files

Tags: bash, unix

I am learning for an approaching exam and I've been learning more and more about bash.
One of the question goes as follows:
   - Get at least 11 arguments (else, give an stderr output and exit)
   - The first argument is going to be a directory
   - The other arguments shall become .txt files in that directory

I can't seem to figure out how to create an N amout of text files ( N=number of arguments).

I have already tried a for loop like in the shown code, but i cannot seem to really figure it out. I should mention that this is shell is being ran in a Linux Subsystem on Windows 10 ( if it's in any way important ).

```
#!/bin/bash

count=$#
if [ $# -lt 11 ]
then
    >&2 echo "Didn't receive enough arguments."
    exit 1 
fi

if [ ! -r $1 ]
then
    echo "Creating file..."
    mkdir $1
    echo "...done."
fi

cd $1

for i in {1..$count}
do
    echo $i
    echo >> $i.txt
done
```

The output should be simple, a directory with the name of $1, in it, N amout of text files. Something similar to this:
   -$2.txt
   -$3.txt
   -$4.txt
   .
   .
   .
   -$N.txt

Comment: `touch file{1..10}` will create `file1, file2, file3, ... file10` in the current directory. (or `touch file{1..10}.txt` to add the `.txt` extension) And... you really don't want `'$'` as part of the filename.

Comment: The problem is still here. I get an unknown amount of arguments, so i would be inclined to do touch file{1..$#}.txt . But all it does is to create a file called file{1..11}.txt (if given 11 arguments).

Comment: You cannot use a variable inside the brace expansion `{1..}` without using `eval`. You can loop `for ((i=0; i < $#; i++)); do touch file$i.txt; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following

```
#!/bin/bash

count=5

for i in {0..5}
do
echo $i
done
```

will output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and the following

```
for i in {0..$count}
do
echo $i
done
```

will output:

```
{1..5}
```

The reason for this is the order in which things occur in bash. Brace expansion occurs before variables are expanded.

So, you should change your `for loop` for the solution to work. A solution using `seq` like the following will make your script work.

```
for i in $(seq 1 $count)
do
    echo "$i"
    echo >> $i.txt
done
```

You can also use a c style for loop

```
for ((i=0; i<=count; i++));
```

There are many other ways. Please see the below references for more:
[Reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash) [Reference 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55392/in-bash-is-it-possible-to-use-an-integer-variable-in-the-loop-control-of-a-for)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has solved the problem. I will read those references.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear why files are named `1.txt, 2.txt, ...`.  To me, *The other arguments shall become .txt files in that directory* sounds like the files should be named according to the respective argument.  That can be done in a loop like so:

```sh
    #! /bin/sh

    if [ $# -lt 11 ]
    then
        >&2 echo "Didn't receive enough arguments."
        exit 1 
    fi

    # errors given
    mkdir "$1" && cd "$1" || exit 1

    while [ $# -ge 2 ]; do
        shift
        touch "$1.txt"
    done
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized my mistake a few hours after I have posted the question. I have modified the code like this so I can create a .txt file with whatever name I get. Thanks for the response!