# Shell script: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: bash, shell, sh

This is a very weird problem. I run test.sh using `sh test.sh` but it returns an error as mentioned in the subject line.

Here's the code for reference:

```
#!/bin/bash

foreach n ( 1 2 3 4 5 )
  echo $n
end
```

It's just a simple loop but it won't execute. Complete error below:

```
test.sh: 3: test.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: it doesn't work because it isn't a valid bash syntax

Comment: See how to iterate over a range in `bash` here - [How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/169511/5291015)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `foreach` in bash. What you've tried works in `tcsh` or `csh`.

The corresponding bash syntax is

```
for n in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do
    echo $n
done
```

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` is not available in bash. It is `for` instead.

For simple range based iterations,

```
for n in {1..5};
do
  echo $n;
done
```

works in reverse too: `{5..1}`
Alphabets: `{a..z} {z..a}`

For more range based iterations with `step != 1`, use `seq`

Comment: Prefer a C-style for loop to `seq` (which may or may not even be available).

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for n in  1 2 3 4 5
do
  echo $n
done
```