# Terminal Commands: Looping number

Tags: python-3.x, macos, terminal

I want to change this python3 code:

```
for i in range(3,70):
    print (i)
```

into code that runs in macOS Mojave terminal

I am guessing something like:

```
for i in {3..70}; do print(i); done
```

?

Comment: you meant bash command or script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close but - use `echo` instead of print. With the following bash syntax:

```
for i in {3..70}
do
    echo $i
done
```

This question has a wealth of information on this topic:

[How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a variable instead of constant values, you can use this:

`for i in $(seq 1 $VAR); do echo $i; done`