# Using an input variable in a 'For Loop' in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I am trying to use the `#REPLY` input variable in the following `for` loop code below;

If I use syntax such as **`for i in {60..0}`** then it works fine however; trying the input variable from the read statement "**for i in {$REPLY..0}**" it fails. It appears that the read does not recognize the input as an integer value; can someone assist please?, thank you.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
clear
tput cup 5
read -p "What is the number of seconds? "
echo "Started:" $(date)
echo " "
echo " "
echo "Countdown Timer"
echo " "

for i in {$REPLY..0}
do
  tput cup 10 $1
  printf '%dh:%dm:%ds\n' $(($i/3600)) $(($i%3600/60)) $(($i%60))
  tput civis
  sleep 1
done
tput cnorm
echo " "
echo "Finished:" $(date)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you **can't** use a variable in *brace expansion*. So, the solution is simple *[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) arithmetic* form loop :

```
for ((i=REPLY; i>=0; i--)); do
    [...]
```

---

<sup>...and **please**, no responses with the evil `eval`, thanks</sup>

Comment: That worked, thank you very much for your great assistance.