# Bash shell task within for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have two files:

`temp_bandstructure.dat` has the following format

```
# spin    band          kx          ky          kz          E(MF)          E(QP)        Delta E kn  E(MF)5dp
#                        (Cartesian coordinates)             (eV)           (eV)           (eV)     (eV)
     1      22     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000   -3.021665798   -4.022414204   -1.000748406 1   -3.02167
     1      22     0.00850     0.00000     0.00000   -3.026245712   -4.027334803   -1.001089091 2   -3.02625
     1      22     0.01699     0.00000     0.00000   -3.039924052   -4.061680485   -1.021756433 3   -3.03992
9000 more rows
```

`mf_pband.dat` has 46 header rows followed by the following

```
  1     0.00000   -55.55593   0.998   0.000 ...20 more columns
9000 more rows
```

I have a nested for loop that compares column 1 and 3 of every row in `mf_pband.dat` against column 9 and 10 of every row in `temp_bandstructure.dat`. If the numbers in match within a value of 0.00001, then the script will print out the entire row of `mf_pband.dat` to a cache file.

I wrote a working for loop that gets the job done, but at a very slow pace:

```
kmax=207
bandmin=$(cat bandstructure.dat | awk 'NR==3''{ print$2 }')
bandmax=$(tac bandstructure.dat | awk 'NR==1''{ print$2 }')
nband=$(($bandmax-$bandmin+1))
nheader=46


for ((i=3;i<=$(($kmax*$nband+2)); i++)); do
    kn=$(awk -v i=$i 'NR==i''{ print$9 }'  temp_bandstructure.dat)
    emf=$(awk -v i=$i 'NR==i''{ print$10 }'  temp_bandstructure.dat)
    
    for ((j=$(($nheader+1));j<=$(($kmax*$nband+$nheader)); j++)); do
        kn_mf_pband=$(awk -v j=$j 'NR==j''{ print$1 }'  mf_pband.dat)
        emf_mf_pband=$(awk -v j=$j 'NR==j''{ print$3 }'  mf_pband.dat)
        if [ "$kn" = "$kn_mf_pband" ] && (( $(echo "$emf - $emf_mf_pband <= 0.00001" |bc -l) )) && (( $(echo "$emf_mf_pband - $emf <= 0.00001" |bc -l) ))
        then
            awk -v j=$j 'NR==j' mf_pband.dat >> temp_copying_cache.dat
            echo $i $j $kn $kn_mf_pband $emf $emf_mf_pband
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

Now I'm trying to send one of the for loop to background tasks so I can run many of them in parallel. The modified code does not give errors, but shows no progress neither:

```
task(){
    kn_mf_pband=$(awk -v j=$j 'NR==j''{ print$1 }'  mf_pband.dat)
    emf_mf_pband=$(awk -v j=$j 'NR==j''{ print$3 }'  mf_pband.dat)
    if [ "$kn" = "$kn_mf_pband" ] && (( $(echo "$emf - $emf_mf_pband <= 0.00001" |bc -l) )) && (( $(echo "$emf_mf_pband - $emf <= 0.00001" |bc -l) ))
    then
        awk -v j=$j 'NR==j' mf_pband.dat >> temp_copying_cache.dat
        echo $i $j $kn $kn_mf_pband $emf $emf_mf_pband
    fi
}


for ((i=3;i<=$(($kmax*$nband+2)); i++)); do
    kn=$(awk -v i=$i 'NR==i''{ print$9 }'  temp_bandstructure.dat)
    emf=$(awk -v i=$i 'NR==i''{ print$10 }'  temp_bandstructure.dat)
    
    for j in {$(($nheader+1))..$(($kmax*$nband+$nheader))}; do
        ((i=i%20)); ((i++==0)) && wait
        task "$j" &
    done
done
wait
```

Can anyone tell me why the tasks are not running and more importantly, how can I get them to run properly?

Comment: Try to fix the errors pointed out by https://www.shellcheck.net/ first. Especially the brace expansion in `for j in {$(($nheader+1))..$(($kmax*$nband+$nheader))}` which does not expand because of the variables. Anyways, this is so slow because you read the same file over and over again. `for i ...; do awk -v i=$i 'NR==i'; done` has quadratic time complexity. You could try to rewrite the script in `awk` only to make it tremendously faster.

Comment: @Socowi,can you give a brief example with awk so I can emulate?

Comment: Reading the whole file from the beginning to just find a numbered line is silly. Much more efficient to read line-by-line; see [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) -- if you can't just do all the logic in native awk.

Comment: @Jacek I added an answer with an skeleton of such an `awk` script.

Comment: BTW, note that `cat somefile | awk ...` is slower than `awk ... <somefile` or `awk ... somefile` -- you're telling the shell to start a separate `/usr/bin/cat` executable and make awk read from a FIFO connected to that executable instead of letting awk read directly from the real file. For some programs like `tail`, `wc -c` or `sort` it's even more inefficient, because reading from a FIFO means that they can't skip straight to the end of the file (as `tail` does), or get the file's size in constant time (as `wc -c` does), or read parts of the file in parallel (as `sort` does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in

```
for j in {$(($nheader+1))..$(($kmax*$nband+$nheader))}; do
    ((i=i%20)); ((i++==0)) && wait
    task "$j" &
done
```

Here, the brace expansion `{$(($nheader+1))..$(($kmax*$nband+$nheader))}` does *not* expand to a list of numbers, but to the literal string `{47..1234}` (actual number for `1234` depends on your file contents).
Then you start `task '{47..1234}' &` which does nothing, because in `task` you try to extract values with `awk -v j='{47..1234}' 'NR==j'`, but `NR` is never `{47..1234}`.
To fix this, use `seq` or `for ((...; ...; ...))`. See [How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/169511/6770384).

Anyways, your script is slow because you read the same file over and over again (and because you are starting up a lot of processes). `for i ...; do awk -v i=$i 'NR==i'; done` has quadratic time complexity. You could try to rewrite the script in `awk` only to make it tremendously faster. First, read one of the files into an array and keep it in memory, then process the other file.

Here is a skeleton of such an `awk` script. The idiom `FNR==NR` is only true when processing the first file.

```
awk -v bandmax="$(tail -n1 bandstructure.dat | awk '{print $2}')" -v nheader=46 '
  FNR==NR && NR>nheader { kn_mf_pband[NR-nheader]=$9; em_mf_pband[NR-nheader]=$10 }
  FNR==NR { next }
  # because of the `next` the following rules are only processed for the 2nd file
  FNR==3 { bandmin=$2 }
  FNR>2 {
    # here you can use for loops to iterate over the stored values in
    # kn_mf_pband[...] and em_mf_pband[...]
  }
' mf_pband.dat bandstructure.dat
```

Comment: I've gave AWK a try but am facing some issues. Can you help me take a look in the modified question? Thanks a lot Socowi!

Comment: @Jacek Yes, I can help you. But please don't change your question to something completely different midway. Please open a new question and tag it as `awk`, then [roll back](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68271823/revisions) your question here to its original so that this answer stays valid.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Socowi. Here's the link to the new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68286106/10747564)