# Why isn't this function working? (Beginner bash scripting)

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, loops, shell

So I have a list of a set of numbers going from 1 to 100, I intended to iterate over it to obtain for every number every single number below it. Like 3 = 1 2 3, or 10 = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10. However the function I'm trying to use isn't working.

```
for i in ${BigList[@]:0:100}
do 
for j in $(echo {1..$i})
do 
echo $j;sleep 1 
done 
done
```

The following code is outputing

```
{1..1}
{1..2}
{1..3}
{1..4}
```

When in fact I was trying to get it to output this: 1 --> 1 2 --> 1 2 3 --> 1 2 3 4. Something like this. The goal is to get all the numbers until that particular one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

`$(echo {1..$i})` suffers from the same problem as `{1..$i}` alone: brace expansion precedes parameter expansion; command substitution does nothing to address that. You *could* use `eval`:

```
for j in eval {1..$i}
```

but it's better to avoid `eval` unless absolutely necessary, which it is not here:

```
for ((j=1; j<=$i; j++))
```

Comment: Because of math mode you can write `for ((j=1; j<=i; j++))` instead of `for ((j=1; j<=$i; j++))`.