# Iterate through multiple command line Arugments

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

I have a c++ program that needs command line arguments like this

```
./Program textfile.txt argu1 10
```

It then gives an output on command line, using cout.

However, is there an easy way of inputting

```
./Program textfile.txt argu1 10 
./Program textfile.txt argu1 20 
./Program textfile.txt argu1 30
```

I need the **output in a text** file because I need to run 100 of these.

I rather not do it manual...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write a for loop in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110/how-do-i-write-a-for-loop-in-bash)

Comment: What do you mean by `output`? There is nothing in your question that even references an `output`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working in `bash` shell, you can use:

```
for i in $(seq 10 10 1000)
do
  ./Program textfile.txt $i >> ouitput.txt
done
```

Comment: and to output to a file, use `./Program textfile.txt $i >> ./output.txt` to append each result to `./output.txt` Make sure you use an `endl` at the end of the last `cout` so the results end up on different lines on the output file.

Comment: @vsoftco Thanks for the hint. The answer is updated.