# How do I rewrite a bash 'while' loop as a 'for' loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop

This is my bash scripting code so I want to know How to Rewrite the below Bash script using a “for” loop instead of the “while” loop.

```
  #!/bin/bash
    if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then                
           a=0;                
           if [ -f RandNos ]; then
               rm RandNos;
           fi

           while [ $a -lt $1 ]
           do
               a='expr $a + 1';
               myrand=$RANDOM;

              if [ "$2" "1"]; then
                  echo "No. $a ==> $myrand";
              fi

              echo $myrand>>RandNos
           done                
    else 
        echo "please use with an argument..."
    fi
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why? there is no point in syntactical rewriting...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write a for loop in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110/how-do-i-write-a-for-loop-in-bash)

Comment: The first thing to do should be making it use consistent indents.

Comment: Thanks for every help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply rewriting it with a `for` loop results in:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
   if [ -f RandNos ]; then
      rm RandNos;
   fi
   lim=$(expr $1 - 1)
   as=$(seq 0 $lim)
   for a in $as
   do
      a='expr $a + 1';
      myrand=$RANDOM;
      if [ "$2" "1"]; then  # <- Caveat: conditional is BROKEN
         echo "No. $a ==> $myrand";
      fi
      echo $myrand>>RandNos
   done
else 
   echo "please use with an argument..."
fi
```

But there are several things wrong with the script anyhow. Like the last `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

The short of it: for **counter-based loops**, use the **C-like form of the `for` loop**:

```
    for (( a = 0; a < $1; a++ )); do
        # ... use $a
    done
```

(This replaces `while [ $a -lt $1 ]; do a='expr $a + 1' ...; done`.)

See below for more on the rules that apply inside `(( ... ))`.

---

As for the **rest of your code**:

- **Conditional `[ "$2" "1"]` is broken**: it's missing the mandatory space before `]`

  - With that fixed, it'll only work if `$2` expands to a unary test operator such as `-n`.
  - Perhaps you meant `if [[ -z $myrand ]]; then`, to check if `$RANDOM` resulted in a nonempty string?

- `a='expr $a + 1'` - which you don't need anymore with the `for` loop - doesn't actually invoke `expr`, because you're using *single quotes* - you'd need *backticks* (`) instead, or, preferably, the modern equivalent: `$(expr $a + 1)`. However, with arithmetic evaluation, this could be simplified to `(( ++a ))`.
- `[ ... ]` conditionals work in bash, but they're provided for POSIX compatibility - **use `[[ ... ]]` as the bash-specific alternative, which is more robust, has more features, and is faster**.
- bash **statements only need terminating with `;` if you place *multiple* on a *single line***

  - Note that bash considers `do ...` and `then ...` separate statements, hence you often see `if ...; then` and `for ...; do`.

- In general, I encourage you to **syntax-check your shell code at http://shellcheck.net** - it's a great tool for detecting syntax problems.

---

Note how **different rules apply inside `(( ... ))`** compared to elsewhere in `bash`:

- spaces around the `=` in the variable assignment are *allowed*.
- referencing a variable without the `$` prefix (`a++`) is *allowed*.
- `<` performs *numerical* comparison (whereas inside `[[ ... ]]` it's *lexical*) -i.e., it's the more natural equivalent to `-lt` inside `[ ... ]` or `[[ ... ]]`.
- several other mathematical and even bit-wise operators are supported
- ...

All these different rules apply when bash operates in an ***arithmetic* context**, which applies to `(( ... ))`, `$(( ... ))`, array subscripts, and other cases.
For all the rules, run `man bash` and read the `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` section.

Answer (score 1):

Several things can be improved:

```
#!/bin/bash
if (( $# )); then                              # anything but 0 is true
   rm -f RandNos                            # remove if existing, otherwise fail silently
   for ((a=0; a<$1; a++)); do
      myrand=$RANDOM

#  what is the intention here?
      (( $2 > 1 )) && echo "No. $a ==> $myrand"
      echo "$myrand" >> RandNos
   done
else
   echo "please use with an argument..."
fi
```

not sure what your intention was with the [ "$2" "1" ] expression. it is probably not what I made from it.

```
for ((a=1; a<=$1; a++)); do
```

may reflect your intended logic better, as you use $a for output only after incrementing it. as pointed out and corrected by @mklement0

Comment: `((a=0; a<$1; a++))` and `((a=0; a<$1; ++a))` are _the same_: inside the loop, `$a` starts with `0` either way, and `$a` is only incremented _after_ each iteration - in other words: it doesn't matter whether you use a pre- or post-increment. If you truly wanted to start with `1`, use `((a=1; a<=$1; a++))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ];then
    echo "First argument must be number".
    exit 1;
fi

for a in `seq $1`
do
     ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

## !/bin/bash

```
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then

a=0;
    if [ -f RandNos ]; then
        rm RandNos;
    fi
    for (( i=$a; i<$1; i++ ))

    do
   
    myrand=$RANDOM;
    if [ "$2" = "1" ]; then
        echo "No. $a ==> $myrand";
    fi
    echo $myrand >> RandNos
    done
else
    echo "please use with an argument..."
fi
```