# Bash Loop 2 Arrays

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to create a loop for a couple of arrays but I get this error:

```
./bash.sh: 3: ./bash.sh: source[0]=/media/jon/my\ directory/: not found
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
sourceFiles[1]=/media/jon/ACER/Documents\ and\ Settings/Laura/Documents/Shared
destinationFiles[1]=/media/jon/My\ Book/Shared

for index in ${!sourceFiles[@]}
do
  sudo rsync -a --delete ${sourceFiles[$index]} ${destinationFiles[$index]}
done
```

I'm some what green to bash files and this is terribly frustrating that doing a simple loop is so difficult.

**Update**

I needed a `#!/bin/bash` at the top per the correct answer.

Comment: Run your script through [SpellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/). And personally, I think [this syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/49114/3076724) would be simpler if you want to use indexes.

Comment: @BroSlow Thanks, I'll change it over, it would even be nicer if I could just use a `map2` syntax! Or even just `range(0..4).map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks ok. I think you're not using bash though ("not found" is not a bash error message). Are you perhaps using `/bin/sh`? On many systems that's a minimal POSIX shell, not bash.

A POSIX shell would not recognize `sourceFiles[1]=...` as an assignment and would consequently run it as a command. Hence the "not found" error.

Answer (score 2):

Try enclosing in double quote your variables in your sudo line:

```
sudo rsync -a --delete "${sourceFiles[$index]}" "${destinationFiles[$index]}"
```

Comment: You were both right, but I had tried what you suggested before, but the underlying problem was pdw's answer. Thanks for your help.