# Simple For Loop in Bash

Tags: bash

I am not understanding why this code is not sending the correct information to netcat.

Not sure what to try

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0000..9999}

do
 echo UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ $i | nc localhost 30002
done
```

Goal is to send a hashed password as well as a 4 digit pin over netcat to port 30002 on localhost. Netcat will return the goal password after receiving the correct password/pin combination.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a for loop in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110/how-do-i-write-a-for-loop-in-bash)

Comment: also, host/port seems in the wrong order.

Comment: Your shell is `/bin/sh` and `{0000..9999}` is something bash understands. Probably you want `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @karakfa edited. it was correct in the bash file, however, I posted it to the site wrong.

Comment: @KamilCuk I ran it as "bash bash.sh", however, I have edited the file and will edit the post to reflect the change to #!/bin/bash

Comment: @wiregh0st Which version of `bash` are you using? Zero-padding of brace expansions wasn't added until bash 4. If you are using an earlier version (such as the one that ships with macOS), then something like `{00..10}` expands to `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` instead of `00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10`.

Comment: @chepner bash version 4.4.12

Comment: What's the output of `$i` if you drop the pipe to `nc`? `0 1 2 ...` or `0000 0001 0002`? Or does the loop only run once with `{0000..9999}` as the value of `$i`?

Comment: "not sending the correct information" - What _is_ it sending?

Answer (score 1):

Your shebang suggests you are using a shell that doesn't support brace expansion. Use `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever path is correct) if you intend to use `bash`-specific features. Per your update, it sounds like you are using an older version of `bash` that doesn't zero-pad the result of a brace expansion.

Brace expansion is typically meant for interactive use, to decrease key strokes. In a script, either use

```
for ((i=0; i< 10000; i++)); do
  printf 'UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ %04d\n' | nc localhost 30002
done
```

or a POSIX-compliant while loop.

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -lt 10000 ]; do
  printf 'UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ %04d\n' | nc localhost 30002
  i=$((i+1))
done
```