# Is there an efficient way to executing a program with similar names using python in the terminal?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, pymupdf

I'm trying to process PDFs using PyMuPDF and I'm running this python file called process_pdf.py in the terminal.

```
> import sys, fitz
> fname = sys.argv[1]  # get document filename
> doc = fitz.open(fname)  # open document
> out = open(fname + ".txt", "wb")  # open text output
> for page in doc:  # iterate the document pages
> text = page.get_text().encode("utf8")  # get plain text (is in UTF-8)
> out.write(text)  # write text of page
> out.close()
```

Then I would feed in a pdf in the terminal such as `python process_pdf.py 1.pdf`. This would then produce 1.txt (text version of 1.pdf). A question I have is that can I make a simple program in the terminal that can iterate `python process_pdf.py document_name.pdf` multiple times like how a for-loop works? This is because the file names are sequential numbers.

I thought about making a for-loop such as

```
> for i in range(1,101): 
>     python process_pdf.py i.pdf
```

But that isn't how python works. P.S. Sorry if this doesn't make any sense; I'm very new into coding :(

Comment: To create the file names use [str formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) - qute a few Q&A's here on SO regarding making file names/paths in a for loop

Comment: Also, the platform you're using makes a difference.  Meaning, Linux answers and Windows answers may be very different.

Comment: [Run a Python script from another Python script, passing in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-arguments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes. you can execute any process with python, including python.exe (or /usr/bin/python3 if on linux) and give it any parameters you want.

subprocess.popen, os.system, etc.

There are some better ways mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script) for specifically running python scripts from python. (runpy)

**but...** this feels like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/1189062).

how about simply generating the file names in the code?

```
import sys, fitz

for i in range(1,101): 
   fname = f"{i}.pdf"  # get document filename
   doc = fitz.open(fname)  # open document
   out = open(fname + ".txt", "wb")  # open text output
   for page in doc:  # iterate the document pages
       text = page.get_text().encode("utf8")  # get plain text (is in UTF-8)
       out.write(text)  # write text of page
   out.close()
```

also, im unfamiliar with "fitz" but maybe you need to close the "doc" file.
check out the ["with" statement](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/with-open-in-python-with-statement-syntax-example/).

---

for the sake of completeness,
[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49125/4935162) how you could do it in your current state, without python, but with a for loop in bash

Comment: Maybe you should just write your answer *correctly* using `with`: `with open(fname + ".txt", "wb") as out:.....`

Comment: maybe. didn't wanna overwhelm him with "nice to have"s

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the for loop from the python shell and you don't want to use subprocess then rewrite the module and put the instructions in a function.

**process_pdf.py**

```
import sys, fitz

def func(fname):
    doc = fitz.open(fname)  # open document
    with open(fname + ".txt", "wb") as out:  # open text output
        for page in doc:  # iterate the document pages
            # get plain text (is in UTF-8)
            # write text of page
```

Import the function in the python shell and call it in the for loop.

```
>>> from process_pdf import func
>>> for i in range(1,101):
...     func('{}.pdf'.format(i))
...     # func(f'{i}.py')
...
```

Or import the module and call the function using dot notation.

```
>>> import process_pdf
>>> for i in range(1,101):
...     process_pdf.func('{}.pdf'.format(i))
...     # process_pdf.func(f'{i}.py')
...
```